When im typing '' on keyboard the VS Code editor is giving me ""cursor"
So when even I'm typing " on keyboard the editor should give me something like "cursor " but instead I'm getting ""cursor" it is happening with ' and ` too. I think the problem is auto close overtype setting as when it is on never VS Code do this but when on other then VS Code gives something like ""cursor which is also annoying. I have done everything up to this point reinstalling VS Code and other stuff but i got no results.
When i pressed shift " i expected the result to be "cursor" but i got ""cursor" instead

Could you also include any related settings? (i.e your settings.json file) Does this work on all files? What happens if you restart both VS Code and your computer?

Welcome! 1) Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. 2) In what language modes does this happen? 3) Does this happen if you reload with extensions diabled?
